# Converting base64 to Image in Flutter Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this image as a base64 String which I then want to convert to image in BoxDecoration like so:

```
 Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: Utility.imageFromBase64String(drink.image))),
```

Here is the function that decodes the String to Image.

**Function**

```
    class Utility {
  static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64String),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }}
```

However, I am getting an error in BoxDecoration:

```
The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'
```

The error is in this part, I suppose I can't put in Image since it asks for ImageProvider:

```
image: DecorationImage(image: Utility.imageFromBase64String(drink.image))
```

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` property from `DecorationImage` is of type `ImageProvider<object>` not `Image`.

Return a `MemoryImage` from `imageFromBase64String` like so

```
  static MemoryImage imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return MemoryImage(
      base64Decode(base64String)
    );
  }
```

Then this.

```
image: DecorationImage(
  image: Utility.imageFromBase64String(drink.image),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

Comment: That was a simple solution, don't know why I was so hung up on keeping the Image. Appreciated!